# Counting sequences with $1 \le a < b < c < d \le 10$

Tags: combinatorics

How would I count the sequences in the following question:

> How many sequences (the sequences are only 4 terms) of positive integers $1 \le a < b < c < d \le 10$ are there?

**EDIT:** I mean that $1 \le a$ and $d \le 10$

I'm familiar with the stars-and-bars counting method, but is it applicable here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that just ${8 \choose 2}$ ? The numbers you got to choose are $b$ and $c$, and they can neither be $1$ nor $10$ (because of strong ineq.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the stars and bars method being applicable directly.

Do you mean $a=1, d=10$?

I am assuming what you mean is $1\leq a< b<c<d\leq10$.

However there is a slightly different way of thinking about this. You could choose 4 numbers out of $\{1,2\dots,10\}$ and then force an arrangement on them.

So the total number of ways(sequences) would be $\binom{10}{4}.$

By forcing an arrangement I mean, if, say, you choose the four numbers $2,6,5,9$, then $\{2,5,6,9\}$ is the only valid sequence you could make out of this selection. So for every selection of four out of ten items you make, you get exactly one sequence.

You could do the same for $a=1,d=10$ too.
In that case you only have to select $b,c$ out of 8 elements $\{2,3\dots,9\}$.

Comment: I didn't mean that sorry please read my edit

Comment: My answer still holds.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer! Sorry I didn't read it at first. But your answer is helpful thanks! I'll accept it when i can.

Comment: Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed $a=1$ and $d=10$, so we're simply left with counting the number of ordered pairs $(b,c)$ that satisfy $1\lt b\lt c\lt 10$.

Assuming that $b,c$ are integers, we have to select $2$ values out of the set $\{2,3,4,\ldots,9\}$ such that $b\lt c$.

This is simply choosing $2$ elements out of $8$ elements neglecting the order of arrangement.

Thus, we have $\dbinom{8}{2}=28$ sequences possible.

Comment: I didn't mean that sorry please read my edit

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for this type of problem is (useful when there are more complex conditions):

$$\begin{align}
\text{Total} &= \sum_{b=2}^9 \sum_{c=b+1}^9 1
\\ &= \sum_{b=2}^9 9 - b
\\ &= 8 \times 9 - \sum_{b=2}^9 b
\\ &= 8 \times 9 - (9+2)\times\frac{(9 - 2 + 1)}{2}
\\ &= 28
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate what the two summations are? :)

Comment: @Arpan The summation is "pick a value of $b$ between $2$ and $9$, then pick a value of $c$ between $b+1$ and $9$, there is $1$ way to choose the remaining values".  If that isn't enough, could you be more specific what isn't clear enough?

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now!